# Graphic Image would not able to pick image based upon theme

Tags: css, jsf-2, primefaces

I have 3 different Theme in my project . All themes are working fine after changes context -param value  into web.xml 
 it is like my current theme is 
 `<context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>NSFPortalGreenTheme</param-value>
   </context-param>`

But during theme change ,I found that primefaces is unable to get the image from IMAGE folder of current theme

I have a code line for image is as below 
 `<p:graphicImage library="images" alt="NSF" name="logo.png"></p:graphicImage>`

How to pick images in different Theme.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have primefaces 3.4+ as the library and name attributes were added only in version 3.4.

The directory structure should be something like this:

```
--resources
----theme1
-------images
----theme2
-------images
```

and then you can use specify the library name as the theme name in the `<p:graphicImage>` library attribute like this:

```
<p:graphicImage library="theme1" alt="NSF" name="images/logo.png" />
```